# Sorting an XDocument based on name of XElement

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have an XML file like this:

```
 <file name="picture1.jpg"/>
 <file name="file1.txt"/>
 <folder name="subfolder">
      <file name="picture2.jpg"/>
      <file name="file2.txt"/>
      <folder name="anotherfolder">
           <file name="file3.txt"/>
      </folder>
 </folder>
 <folder name="anotherfolder">
 </folder>
```

It needs to be sorted like this:

```
<folder name="anotherfolder">
 </folder>
 <file name="file1.txt"/>
 <file name="picture1.jpg"/>
 <folder name="subfolder">
      <folder name="anotherfolder">
           <file name="file3.txt"/>
      </folder>
      <file name="file2.txt"/>
      <file name="picture2.jpg"/>
 </folder>
```

The code I have to sort is:

```
public static XDocument Sort(XDocument file)
    {
        return new XDocument(Sort(file.Root));
    }
    private static XElement Sort(XElement element)
    {
        XElement newElement = new XElement(element.Name,
            from child in element.Elements()
            orderby child.Name.ToString()
            select Sort(child));
        if (element.HasAttributes)
        {
            foreach (XAttribute attrib in element.Attributes())
            {
                newElement.SetAttributeValue(attrib.Name, attrib.Value);
            }
        }
        return newElement;
    }
```

It does the job...but only partly. It sorts FILE based on name attribute separately from FOLDER. I would like them to be considered together for the sorted xml. What should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this code does *not* order child elements by name *attribute*; it sorts by *element name*:

```
orderby child.Name.ToString()
```

What you need to do is get the value of the "name" attribute (case sensitive!) instead. This is possible with `child.Attribute("name")`, but you need to get the `.Value` of this while watching out for `null` attributes; the code is going to be slightly awkward to write inline.

Personally I find this version with `child.Attributes` (that returns a collection) more convenient:

```
orderby child.Attributes("name").Select(a => a.Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.OrderBy(e=>e.Attribute("name").Value)
```

do this recursively at any level if you wanna sort or just use this method on an `IEnumerable` of nodes to sort them